# Using "= in preamble with babel

Tags: babel, hyphenation, german

I have noticed a strange behaviour when switching between the packages `german` and `babel` with the `german` option. There is obviously a difference in how `"=` is handled in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german}
\title{Some"=Thing}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
Some"=Text.
\end{document}
```

yields the following result:

[image]

while the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\title{Some"=Thing}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
Some"=Text.
\end{document}
```

does not handle the `"=` in the `\title{}` command correctly:

[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour? How can I make the `babel` package behave like the `german` package? (I have to switch from `german` to `babel` because some packages like `fancyref` use the wrong translations if only `german` is used.)

Comment: `\shorthandon{"}` and later back off again `\shorthandoff{"}`

Comment: Place `\title` after `\begin{document}` (which is what I always recommend, contrarily to others). On the other hand, hyphenating the title shouldn't be allowed.